# JSF Error Message and Info Message is not working from backing bean

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I need a bit help here while setting messages to faces context from a backing bean , 
My page design layout is as follows.Also its using a common layout for all the pages.

***ContactUs.xhtml***

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="#{language.layout}"> //CommonLayout.xhtml //common template
<ui:define name="content">

<div class="input-cont">
<h:form styleClass="login-form">
<h:messages errorClass="error medium" layout="table" />
<p:inputText value="#{customerBean.contactUsDTO.email}"
        id="useremail" name="useremail" type="email"
            styleClass="input-text" placeholder="Email" />

<p:inputTextarea value="#{customerBean.contactUsDTO.comments}"
name="txtFeedback" id="txtFeedback"
styleClass="input-text comment-area" placeholder="Comments"</p:inputTextarea>

<div class="btn-cont labels-to-inputs">
<h:commandLink action="#{customerBean.contactUs}"
styleClass="next-btn login-btn ord-btn">Submit</h:commandLink>
</div>
</h:form>
```

***CommonLayout.xhtml*** Is as follows

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    >


<f:view locale="#{language.locale}">  
<h:head>

 <h:body>
     <div class="container">
<ui:insert name="leftNav"> <!-- Left Navigation -->
                        <ui:include src="commonLeft.xhtml" />
                    </ui:insert>

                 <div id="content"> <!-- External Page Contents Starts -->
                    <ui:insert name="content">

                    </ui:insert>
                </div>  <!-- External Page Contents Ends -->
</div>
</h:body>
 </f:view>
</html>
```

And ***ContactBean.java***
This bean is session scoped under facesconfig.xml file

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class ContactBean{

public String contactUs() {
    String response="success" //Testing purpose
    if(!response.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                    {raiseError("Service is temporarily unavailable, Try again later");


                    }
                    System.out.println("Response from email is  "+response);
                }
                else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                    System.out.println("Response from email is  "+response);
                    {raiseInfo("Thanks for gettting in touch with Us, We will contact you soon");

                    }

                }
}
    return "ContactUs";

}

public void raiseError(String msgText){
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msgText, msgText);
    fc.addMessage(null, msg);
}//raiseError

public void raiseInfo(String infoMsg){
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, infoMsg, infoMsg);
    fc.addMessage(null, msg);

}//raiseError

}
```

This raiseInfo and rasieError messages are not showing any messages to that contact-form page, after adding those as a new message object into faces context also , Its not showing up. What could be the possibly error happening.

Comment: @Abhishekyou are not sending string parameter correctly into method raiseError from contactUs() method. See my answer

Comment: Hi, ArgaPK there was another overridden method with a single parameter what i was using like raiseInfo method, Though your solution didn't help in this case also

Comment: i have find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out by @ArgaPK, you have missed to terminate first string parameter and start the second string parameter in the  below call of raiseError inside contactUs method, instead of 2 parameters it is one String and hence the error:
raiseError("Service is temporarily unavailable, Try again later");

It should have been a compile time error.

Comment: there is actually two strings(parameters) which are passing into raiseError method;  raiseError(String msgText,String id);

Comment: @ArgaPK: no, ypu are wrong in this regard and LNP is fully right, but I think OP did not post all code. It would otherwise have been a compile error. And you effectively state the same... only your solution is worse sive you assume the , is the separator and now pass a very weird id.., "Try again later"? Weird

Comment: @Kukeltje I didn't said that there is no error.  See the id can be any String but it should be a String.  Here id is this string "Try again later" which is looking weird.

Comment: No, **you created ot as a second string in your answer**, it is missing in the op as stated by the other mpre correct answer. A real id should be there OR a method with in parameter shoy;d exist. The code posted above **cannot run** othetwise

Comment: @Lnp there is some rendering issue is there with JSFmessage component, which i am not able to find out. If from the xhtml page itself any error messages comes like for blanks input elments then its correctly showing the error , but when adding a message from backing bean , then its not showing the message in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution:
 you have to add `<p:growl>` tag in your xhtml form.

```
<h:form styleClass="login-form">

<p:growl id="growl" life="2000" />

.... 
<h:commandLink action="#{customerBean.contactUs}"
styleClass="next-btn login-btn ord-btn">Submit</h:commandLink>

</h:form>
```

Comment: h:messages should also work right? if p:growl works.

Comment: did you try with p:growls?

Comment: well, i never tried with h:message, but use p:growl successfuly.